# Dependency error installing curl

Tags: apt, dependencies, curl

I wanted to install curl to program in C. However, I encountered a dependency problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install the dependencies and received this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgnutls-dev : Depends: libgnutls-openssl27 (= 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1) but 3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1ppa1~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have checked `libgnutls-openssl27` version to be 3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1ppa1~trusty.

Any help?

Comment: Instead of downgrading the package, I would suggest you to disable third part ppa.

Comment: Yeah! I might accidentally added that. However, how do I know which one is causing problem?

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy libgnutls-openssl27`

Comment: I don't know whether that would be helpful because already I have downgraded the package:

`$:apt-cache policy libgnutls-openssl27

libgnutls-openssl27:
  
Installed: 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1

  Candidate: 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1

  Version table:
 *** 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12.23-12ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: It seems PPA containing  version is disabled.`3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1ppa1~trusty`. You have latest version of `libgnutls-openssl27` available in [trusty repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgnutls-openssl27). No need to do any thing extra. enjoy.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will you care to explain what's `PPA containing version`? I mean 3.2.16 seems like a later version than 2.12.23. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry it was a type. Ubuntu official repository does not contain `libgnutls-openssl27` version `3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1ppa1~trusty`. It means it was coming from some third part PPA which you might have added earlier(probably [this](https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/ubuntu/staging-deletedppa116/+build/6703603)). You can use `apt-cache policy` command to find the source of a specific package. But in the output of  this command I can see that version `3.2.16-1ubuntu2.1ppa1~trusty` is not listed. It means somehow it is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
sudo aptitude install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

It firstly gave me one naive solution to accept which I didn't take. (Because nothing was to be installed on that solution!) Then it gave a solution to **downgrade** some packages. I accepted the solution. Now, I don't know whether I did it right! The downgrading may come with some security problem. It would be great if anyone can comment on that.